# How should I tell a Rails Rakefile to load only the tasks I explicitly require?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

Here's what the default Rails 3 Rakefile looks like:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__) 
MyApp::Application.load_tasks
```

This does the following:

- Loads my Rails application. This takes 20 seconds. Most of this time is spent on the `Bundler.require`; Rails itself loads within a second or two.
- Loads any Rake tasks from my gems.
- Loads any Rake tasks from my lib/tasks directory.

How do I write a Rakefile that only does steps 2 and 3, but not step 1 (unless I go the usual route and specify the `:environment` task)?

What would be even better is if I could explicitly require what's needed for each gem's Rake tasks, so that if I don't want to use them, I don't have to load them. (This was the behavior in Rails 2.)